# how to restrict form submission from certain url - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

if i want to block form submission from the following url, how can i do that?

```
http://laravel.dev/iframe/123
```

This url will generate dynamically and we will not use any javascript(only user's created JS will be there) on that page to block form submission.

I need to protect routes which are accepting inputs. For example:

1. Register user (usersController@store)
2. or other routes which are accepting forms.

is their any way , i can filter certain routes to prevent form submission in Laravel?

how to tell laravel to ignore forms submission from certain urls?

Comment: Could you give a little more information regarding the use case? As in, for what reason would you be blocking URLs?

Comment: I am developing an application like codepen, jsfiddle. To generate preview, i need to link a page which will generate the output. I have tried to generate output using js but it is not cross browser friendly. In Iframe, Firefox (may be IE as well) not loading external css or JS files without user interaction during page load. However, in Chrome and Safari its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
$referer = Request::header('referer');
$restrictedList = Config::get('app.restricted'); // obviously change this to pull from your source

if(in_array($referer, $restrictedList))
    App::abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
```

Comment: Nice idea. I will try this. What is the best place to put this code. i don't want to check every single of the routes(only put and post). thanks.

Comment: One issue. `http://laravel.dev/iframe/123` will be dynamic. URL would be something like the following `http://laravel.dev/iframe/xyz`, `http://laravel.dev/iframe/9833sa`. so, it is impossible to know full url. is their any way to get the route name from url?

Comment: I would place this in the controller actions that will handle it. If it spans multiple controllers, make a filter for it and use the 'before' attribute on the route to run the filter.

As for getting the current route name, try either Route::currentRouteName() or Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath(), depending which you need.